# tr border-bottom in inline style does not show

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to add border-bottom to `<tr>` element of table as below but it is not working.

```
<table>
<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid black !important;">
```

It is working when I add the style to `<td>` but not on `<tr>`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot apply a border on `tr` element, you need to apply a border on `td`, or you need to use [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) for your `table` element

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y292h/) *(Applying `border-bottom` to `td`)*

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/y292h/3) *(Applying `border-bottom` to `tr` if used `border-collapse`)*

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}

table tr { /* Use table tr td if not using border-collapse property */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Note: Avoid using *inline* styles, you will feel hard to change them at certain point, also, avoid using `!important` unless required, consider using more specific selectors instead.